# Should I keep every component in separate file? (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue.js and have a timer/stopwatch component which has the following parts built as **separate components**. Every component/part has **its own file**.

- digital clock,
- note,
- controls,
- a couple of other small parts

I combine them in another file lets say **stopwatch.vue** by including them inside of it and use the following code.

```
<div>
  <clock></clock>
  <note></note>
  <controls></controls> 
</div>
```

Then I can import **stopwatch.vue** in another place and do the following

```
<stopwatch></stopwatch>
```

**Should I keep all the components in separate files or it's better to create a single one and keep the code of all the components there?**

Comment: It's better to split it into the components, there are many advantages such as modulartiy, easaier debugging, easaier testing etc...